# Laravel: Access relationship table

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I need to return a list of missions and the current user progress for each mission. For this, I created the following eloquent expression:

```
return DailyMission::with('userProgress')->get();
```

Using the following relationship in my DailyMission Model (daily_missions table):

```
public function userProgress() {
        return $this->hasOne(UserDailyMission::class,'mission_id');
    }
```

The problem is that it's not user specified, which means I get the first progress of random user in my database.

I tried to change the expression into this:

```
return DailyMission::with('userProgress')
        ->where('user_daily_missions.user_id',$user->id)
        ->get();
```

but I get the following error:

```
SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'user_daily_missions.user_id' in 'where clause
```

The user progress is stored at the `user_daily_missions` table using the following structure:

```
id | user_id | mission_id | current_progress
```

Any ideas how to output the progress of the current user instead of a random user? Is there anything wrong with the structure?

Comment: Try using `with(['userProgress' => function($q) use ($user){ $q->where('user_id',$user->id);}])` instead of `->where('user_daily_missions.user_id',$user->id)`

Comment: do you have a $user in your function?

Comment: @NarendrasinghSisodia Thanks! Awesome!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For getting data with specific condition within Eloquent. Laravel provided feature of using `closure/callback` function that'll be bind with your `relationship` defined within your `Model`. So over here you can simply pass a `closure` with extra condition like as

```
return DailyMission::with([
   'userProgress' => function($q) use ($user){ 
      $q->where('user_id',$user->id);
}])->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

I dont know how to get your user id but this should work:

```
 $mission = DailyMission::with('userProgress')->where('id', 'theuserid')->first();

  return $mission;
```

Answer (score 0):

@TheUnreal could you please try by using below code.

```
return DailyMission::whereHas('userProgress', function($q) use ($user) {
    $q->where('user_id', $user->id);
})->get();
```